# What FQDN should I use for Postfix setup in Satellite Mode on Ubuntu VM on VirtualBox?

Tags: postfix, virtualization

I am getting lost with trying to configure Postfix on a Ubuntu 14.04 VM running on VirtualBox.

The VirtualBox has 2 NICs: 

1)NAT and is Internet access through my computer running the VM and 

2)"Host only Adapter" to allow me to SSH into my VM.

I want to run Postfix in Satellite mode - I just want to be able to test ability to send emails with PHP/Wordpress. Not receive emails.

I don't have a FQDN nor a static IP. I am not sure what to use as System Mail name. (Even if I were to put an IP - which IP would I use? The VM IP on NIC 1 or my host IP?) Does it even matter if I am only sending emails?

I am new to this and I have tried installing Postfix twice and it did not work...any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every system has a hostname, it is given by the administrator when the system is installed/set up. It is used by all installed network-related software to identify the machine .

To get the current set hostname, you can just call `hostname` or look in `/etc/hosts`, as the hostname always points to localhost.

The hostname is essential as all network related services use it to reference to the home system. E.g. postfix appends the hostname to email addresses only containing the local part, thus being a valid address. Without the domain part, a email address is not valid as it is unclear which host is responsible.

If you leave the hostname empty, postfix does not know what email is should deliver locally or remote. Also, a hostname can never be an IP address. You don't need a fully qualified domain name in a testing environment.

However, if you are sending mails to the internet and expect to find them in your Inbox, not the Spam directory, you need a complete setup, including an FQDN, correct DNS settings etc.

Comment: I short of assumed that in satellite mode it would be the remote mail server ie: gmail.com, because I am supplying my gmail username/password during config, I thought it is using gmail for everything.